# Ubuntu is playing no Firefox sound if USB hub is connected

Tags: usb, sound, firefox

I have the problem that my Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) is not playing sound in Firefox anymore, if my USB hub is connected (It's an USB-C hub, which also has an an headphone jack, see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjfMC.png) )
[image: sound controll]
as you can see, there are always 2 Firefoxes in the volume control.
If I move the one Firefox volume controller which seems to be off to on, it switches automatically to off.
If I use the Brave or Chrome browser everything works.

If I unplug the USB-Hub, everything works as expected, also in Firefox.

Comment: Have a very similar problem here. When I plug the USB-C hub, both firefox volume control options can be switch on. But the firefox still doesn't play any sound. It worked before. This is the new problem that happens to me today. Reboot the laptop several times and it doesn't help. I have a separate but related issue, the output test in the sound setting page doesn't work when I plug in the USB-C hub.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. When I plug the USB-C hub, both firefox volume control options can be switch on. But the firefox still doesn't play any sound. It worked previously. Reboot the laptop doesn't help.

I solved my problem using [PulseAudio Volume Control](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pavucontrol.1.html). In the playback tab in the control, I can specify the output device of the individual application. I changed the device of firefox to "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" as all other applications, and the problem solved.